# DCM4CHE cannot display Japnese Character

Tags: c++, database, postgresql, dcm4che

I am using dcm4che as my PACS and I am inserting a DICOM file which contains the patient name in Japanese character.
But the web based url of dcm4chee is not supporting Japanese character and showing the patient name as garbled characters( like question marks and squares ).

For DCM4CHE i am using postgresql as the DataBase. In DB properties it is showing 'Encoding as UTF8', 'Collation as English_India.1252' and 'Character Type as English_India.1252'. Does my DB supports Japanese character ?
I am new to Database and any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT:**
This issue was not related to PACS. I obtained a valid DICOM file with Japanese charters( they are using specific character set as \ISO 2022 IR 87 ) and send the same to PACS. Its correctly showing in the PACS. So the issue is with my DICOM file. I also inserted the specific character set as '\ISO 2022 IR 87'. But still I am getting garbled japanese characters.

**I am using MergeCom Dicom utility and using 'MC_Set_Value_From_String' API for inserting the japanese string. Am I missing anything ? Is it not possible to insert Japanese characters by using 'MC_Set_Value_From_String' ?** I am thinking of using the API MC_Set_Value_From_UnicodeString.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve the issue.

The issue was related to the encoding. For Unicode conversion, I was using the windows API "WideCharToMultiByte" with code page was UTF-8. This was not properly converting the Japanese characters which was fixed by using code page as 50222.
You can find all the entire code page from below link.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd317756(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

UTF-8 supports all unicode code points, which includes Japanese. So it is unlikely the database is the issue.

What is the content of the Specific Character Set (0008,0005) tag? The default character encoding for dicom is ASCII. There is a [section](http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/html/part05.html#chapter_H) in the dicom spec providing examples of use with Japanese.

Comment: Thank you. For giving Japanese character support, I am giving specific character set as ISO IR 87. I tried by giving specific character set as 'ASCII'. But still it is showing as garbled characters. Could you suggest any DICOM viewers which supports Japanese characters ? Because I am using MicroDicom which is showing the characters as question marks. I want to confirm that my DICOM file is valid and supports japanese character.

Comment: Part of the problem you may have is finding applications which use a font which support Japanese characters. Consider trying dcm4che's command line dcmdump utility. https://github.com/dcm4che/dcm4che/blob/master/dcm4che-tool/dcm4che-tool-dcmdump/README.md

Comment: I downloaded a DICOM file containing Japanese character from web. I am able to view the same in the DICOM viewer and once i sent the same file to PACS, it is coming correctly( i.e Japanese characters are displayed correctly ). Hence I assume the issue is with my DICOM file only. I could not find out whether the issue is whether while writing to the file using API or while saving the same !!!